# Proving closed subsets of compact sets (in a metric space) are compact.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Let $X$ be a metric space and let $K\subset X$ be a compact set in $X$ and let $E\subset K$ be closed subset of $K$.

I want to prove that $E$ is compact. I have asked this question before also but this time I am trying to prove it differently than the last time.

**Proof:** I'll prove: $E$ is not compact $\implies E $ is not closed relative to $K$. Then contrapositive of it proves the statement that I'm trying to prove.

There exists an open cover $(U_\alpha)$ of $E$ without a finite subcover. 
Here $(U_\alpha)=\{U_\beta \subset K: \beta \in \text{index set and } U_\beta \text{ is open relative to $K.$}\}$ such that $E\subset (U_\alpha)$.

If $E$ is closed relative to $K$ then clearly the set $K - E$ is open rel. to $K$. And therefore, $(K-E)\cup (U_\alpha)$ forms an open cover of $K$ and therefore, $K\subset (K-E)\cup (U_\alpha)$. And since $K$ is compact $\exists$ finitely many indices $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots,\alpha_n$ such that $K\subset (K-E)\cup (U_{\alpha_i}) $, where $i=1,2,\cdots, n$. $\tag 1$
It follows that $E\subset K\subset (K-E)\cup (U_{\alpha_i}) \implies E\subset (U_{\alpha_i}) $ and therefore open cover $(U_\alpha)$ has a finite subcover, which is a contradiction and therefore $E$ is not closed.

**Note:** Since $K\subset K \subset X$, then it can be proven that $K$ is compact in $K$ if and only if $K$ is compact in $X$. Therefore, open covers of $K$ even if they come from $K$ will have a finite subcover. And therefore, there exist $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n$ in $(1)$ above.

Is my proof correct? Thanks.

Comment: More or less the same as https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4091772.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One small point needs clarification. When we say $K$ is compact in $X$ we mean that any cover of $K$ by open sets in $X$ has  finite subcover. But you have used the fact that any cover of $K$ by open sets in $K$ has  finite subcover. This is not wrong but you have to say why this is true.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for sparing time to answer my question. You are right,  I should have used the argument that compactness of $K$ does not depend upon the metric space in which it is embedded in. And so since $K\subset K$, it follows that $K$ is compact in $K$ so open sets in $K$ will do just fine. Please let me know if  that's correct?

Comment: If you are defining compactness through open covers (as is usually done) you have to use the fact any open set in $K$ is just $K \cap U$ for som e open set $U$ in $X$. @Koro

Comment: Sir, I agree with that. Every open set in K is intersection of K with some open set in $X$. But we can remove  $X$ altogether from the picture considering that  $K\subset K\subset X$ so by a theorem that states compactness is independent of set it is embedded in,  $K$ is compact in K if and only if it is compact in $X$. Hence, considering open sets of only $K$ is just fine. Am I right sir? The reason I even mentioned $X$ is because I wanted to emphasize metric space as currently I don't know topological spaces except metric spaces.

Comment: Sir, I have added a note in my post. Is my proof correct now? Thanks.

Comment: @Koro Now it looks OK.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir :).

Answer (score 1):

Seems correct to me except for the fact that Kavi Rama Murthy pointed out but I also think that you are kind of proving the statements directly, since you are doing the contrapositive of the Lemma and then you're supposing that $E$ is closed in $K$.

What would have changed if you simply started with $E$ being closed in $K$ and by "absurd" not compact? The exact same words would have been used.

An other way to prove the statement would have been :

Let $E \subset K$ be a closed set, where $K$ is compact. Let $\{U_\alpha\}$ be an open cover of $E$. Then $\{U_\alpha\} \cup \{E^c\}$, where $E^c$ is the complement of $E$ w.r.t. to $X$, covers $K$. Since $K$ is compact, we can extract a finite subcover $\{E^c, U_{\alpha_1}, U_{\alpha_2}, \ldots, U_{\alpha_n}\}$ from $\{U_\alpha\} \cup \{E^c\}$. Since $E \cap E^c = \varnothing$, we have that $\{ U_{\alpha_1}, U_{\alpha_2}, \cdots, U_{\alpha_n}\}$ is a subcover of $\{U_\alpha\}$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response :). Now that you mention it, I think you are right :) But you have not mentioned $E$ is closed relative to $K$ or $X$. But that's not the problem here. May I request you to please have a look at the "note" I have added in my post where I have mentioned my understanding as to why  finite subcover $(U_\alpha)$ exists? Thanks :)

Comment: @Koro https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53860/compactness-in-mathbbq Does the first answer answers you ?

Comment: I understand that property that you shared in this link and that's what I have added in "note" also (it was not there at the time I'd posted my question. Sorry about that). But comment from @KaviRamaMurthy in the answer seems to imply that considering $U_\alpha$ as intersection of K and some open set in X is the only way. So I need clarification whether my understanding is correct or not.

Comment: So now my understanding is Ok. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Koro Yes it is! You’re welcome